# How to call extension methods in overrideViewDidLoad in swift

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
extension ViewController {


func AddLeftGesture(){
    let SwipeLeft:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyDismissOnSwipeLeft))

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(SwipeLeft)
}

func MyDismissOnSwipeLeft(){

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and What I would like to accomplish is that override the viewDidLoad and 
call  `AddLeftGesture` method so that it'll be part of each VC I make
and I don't have to type it again and again in each viewDidLoad,

is this possible? or do you guys have any other suggestions?

Comment: If `ViewController` is your own class, why not just define it in the class definition proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I don't think it's a good idea, because typically `viewDidLoad` is used for setting most properties and if you would like to override it in a view controller you should write it again.What I can suggest is that to make a base `ViewController` and add this code in the `viewDidLoad` of that and then subclass every viewController from the base view controller , This way whenever you want to change anything you just call `super.viewDidLoad`

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addLeftGesture()
    }
}


class CustomViewController: BaseViewController{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make this class which inherits UITapGestureRecognizer

```
open class BlockTap: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    fileprivate var tapAction: ((UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void)?

public override init(target: Any?, action: Selector?) {
    super.init(target: target, action: action)
}

public convenience init (
    tapCount: Int = 1,
    fingerCount: Int = 1,
    action: ((UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void)?) {
        self.init()
        self.numberOfTapsRequired = tapCount

        #if os(iOS)
        self.numberOfTouchesRequired = fingerCount
        #endif

        self.tapAction = action
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BlockTap.didTap(_:)))
}

open func didTap (_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    tapAction? (tap)
}
}
```

then make an extension of UIView

```
extension UIView {
        public func addTapGesture(tapNumber: Int = 1, action: ((UITapGestureRecognizer) -> ())?) {
            let tap = BlockTap(tapCount: tapNumber, fingerCount: 1, action: action)
            addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Then You can use this as

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         self.view.addTapGesture(action: {[unowned self] (_) in
                //Do whatever on click of View
         })
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's two options AFAIK. Either you can subclass UIViewController and then make all of your controllers inherit from the subclassed one, or you can swizzle  `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()`.

I personally would choose swizzling, although it has one disadvantage - it hides the implementation and might be confusing for a new developer coming onto a project. So make sure you document this properly, somewhere in your project README and in the code as well.

Now for some code examples:

**Subclassing `UIViewController`**

`MyViewController.swift`

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addGesture()
    }

    func addGesture() {
        // Do what you need
    }
}

class OtherViewController: MyViewController {
    // Automatically will add gesture because it's a subclass of  MyViewController
}
```

**Swizzling `viewDidLoad`**

What method swizzling does is, that it exchanges implementations of your methods. That simply means that the name of your function points at code from a different function. For more information on this topic [read this article](https://www.uraimo.com/2015/10/23/effective-method-swizzling-with-swift/).

`UIViewController+Swizzle.swift`

```
static func swizzle(selector originalSelector: Selector,
                    with newSelector: Selector,
                    on targetClass: AnyClass) {
    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(targetClass, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(targetClass, newSelector)

    // If we were able to add the swizzled function, replace methods.
    // Otherwise exchange implementations if method already exists.
    if class_addMethod(targetClass, originalSelector,
                       method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                       method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod)) {

        class_replaceMethod(targetClass, newSelector,
                            method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                            method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
}

extension UIViewController {

    // This function is getting called automatically by the runtime, 
    // when this class is loaded to perform some additional intiialization. 
    // However, this has now been deprecated in Swift, so only option is to 
    // declare a static function which you need to remember to call from 
    // somewhere, preferably early in your app initialization, like your 
    // didFinishLaunching function in AppDelegate or even AppDelegate's init 
    // function. I kept the initialize function in the code as a reference, 
    // however you would probably want to write it like in the comment 
    // below, to silence the warning.
    //
    // class func swizzle()
    //
    open override class func initialize() {
        if self != UIViewController.self { return }

        let swizzlingClosure: () = {
            swizzle(selector: #selector(UIViewController.viewDidLoad),
                             with: #selector(UIViewController.swizzled_viewDidLoad),
                             on: UIViewController.self)
        }()

        swizzlingClosure
    }

    @objc private func swizzled_viewDidLoad() {
        // Calls the original implementation,
        // because implementations are switched.
        swizzled_viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Do whatever you need
        addGesture()
    }

    @objc func addGesture() {
        // Add your gesture
    }
}
```